# What is the right way to implement recaptcha in symfony 3 login?

Tags: symfony, validation, authentication, recaptcha, symfony-3.3

I am using form_login in two different firewalls, one for user, one for admin. I want this to only affect the user one.

What would be the right implementation to have recaptcha on login form?

Some things I'm considering:

- New login form factory which extends the symfony FormLoginFactory, where I can validate the recaptcha
  or
- Overriding the UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener so that form_login uses a new one which validates captcha or
- Having the captcha on its own page and show it only when user enters invalid credentials a number of times

Comment: You can start looking at how it is implemented in the already existence bundles. Just make a search on knpbundles. PS: voted to close because this type of questions are too broad and off-topic here.

Comment: Looks like knpbundles is down, but I have found a good enough solution and I will post it as a comment later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a bundle for this question: https://packagist.org/packages/syspay/login-recaptcha-bundle

Old response:

What I did to solve this problem:

I created a new Security Listener Factory called CaptchaLoginFormFactory which has the following

```
<?php

namespace Project\Bundle\CoreBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory;

use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory\FormLoginFactory;

/**
 * CaptchaLoginFormFactory
 */
class CaptchaLoginFormFactory extends FormLoginFactory
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getKey()
    {
        return 'form_login_captcha';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getListenerId()
    {
        return 'security.authentication.listener.form_login_captcha';
    }
}
```

and a new Authentication Listener called CaptchaFormAuthenticationListener

```
<?php

namespace Project\Bundle\CoreBundle\Security\Firewall;

use Project\Security\CaptchaManager;
use Project\Security\Exception\InvalidCaptchaException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\ParameterBagUtils;

/**
 * CaptchaFormAuthenticationListener
 */
class CaptchaFormAuthenticationListener extends UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener
{
    /** @var CaptchaManager $captchaManager */
    private $captchaManager;

    /**
     * setCaptchaManager
     *
     * @param CaptchaManager $captchaManager
     */
    public function setCaptchaManager(CaptchaManager $captchaManager)
    {
        $this->captchaManager = $captchaManager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function attemptAuthentication(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->captchaManager->isCaptchaNeeded($request)) {
            $requestBag = $this->options['post_only'] ? $request->request : $request;
            $recaptchaResponse = ParameterBagUtils::getParameterBagValue($requestBag, 'g-recaptcha-response');

            if (!$this->captchaManager->isValidCaptchaResponse($recaptchaResponse, $request->getClientIp())) {
                throw new InvalidCaptchaException();
            }
        }

        return parent::attemptAuthentication($request);
    }
}
```

As can be seen they extend the original FormFactory with some changes where before I use the normal authentication listener I use my own methods to validate the captcha.

Then I added it in the CoreBundle::build method

```
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    parent::build($container);

    $extension = $container->getExtension('security');
    $extension->addSecurityListenerFactory(new CaptchaLoginFormFactory());
}
```

and created the services

```
security.authentication.listener.form_login_captcha:
    class: Project\Bundle\CoreBundle\Security\Firewall\CaptchaFormAuthenticationListener
    parent: security.authentication.listener.form
    abstract: true
    calls:
        - [ setCaptchaManager, ['@project.security.captcha_manager'] ]
```

Then in security.yml under the firewall I just use the new factory form_login_captcha with the same options as form_login. This way I can use form_login on another firewall without affecting it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using https://github.com/karser/KarserRecaptcha3Bundle on Symfony 4.4 using a Subscriber. It is just a quick solution, you might want to modify for flexibility.

You will need to modify code to support showing captcha after a number of failed attempts.

I guess you are using different routes for different firewalls. You can check the login route name and apply captcha validation if needed.

[gist code](https://gist.github.com/nuryagdym/ae946b8e696eb6c1a09c510b4ad66c35)

LoginSubcriber.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use App\Form\LoginType;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;


class LoginSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var FormFactoryInterface
     */
    private $formFactory;

    /**
     * @var FlashBagInterface
     */
    private $flashBag;

    public function __construct(FlashBagInterface $flashBag, FormFactoryInterface $formFactory)
    {
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->flashBag = $flashBag;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        /**
         * You can add event subscriber on KernelEvents::REQUEST with priority 9.
         * because class Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener(responsible for registering the events for symfony firewall) has priority 8.
         */
        return array(
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onLogin', 9]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param RequestEvent $event
     */
    public function onLogin(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        if ('public_login' !== $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route')) {
            return;
        }

        //form generation should be in the same way (createdNamed in this case) as in LoginController
        $loginForm = $this->formFactory->createNamed(null, LoginType::class);
        if (!$loginForm->has('captcha')) {
            return;
        }
        $loginForm->handleRequest($event->getRequest());

        if (!$loginForm->isSubmitted()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$loginForm->get('captcha')->isValid()) {
            $errors = $loginForm->get('captcha')->getErrors();
            $message = count($errors) ? $errors[0]->getMessage() : 'Failed to pass robot test';
            $this->flashBag->add(
                'error',
                $message
            );
            $session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();
            $session->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $loginForm->get('_username')->getData());

            //to prevent request to call next event
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($event->getRequest()->getRequestUri()));
        }
    }
}
```

LoginType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use Karser\Recaptcha3Bundle\Form\Recaptcha3Type;
use Karser\Recaptcha3Bundle\Validator\Constraints\Recaptcha3;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class LoginType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('_username', EmailType::class, ['attr' => ['placeholder' => 'email'], 'data' => $options['lastUsername']])
            ->add('_password', PasswordType::class, ['attr' => ['placeholder' => 'password']])
            ->add('_remember_me', CheckboxType::class, ['required' => false])
        ;
        $builder->add('captcha', Recaptcha3Type::class, [
            'constraints' => new Recaptcha3(),
            'action_name' => 'login'
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            //default csrf parameters defined in Symfony codes. without this configuratio csrf check will fail
            'csrf_field_name' => '_csrf_token',
            'csrf_token_id'   => 'authenticate',
          
            'lastUsername' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to align captcha icon to left bottom, using this plugin.